# Randomize password in yaml file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, yaml

I've been trying to update helm values.yaml with a randomized password.

My approach is to add a `placeholder` like

```
global:
    my_password: "password-placeholder"
another_service
    service_password: "password-placeholder"
```

I tried to generate password with `openssl rand -base64 12`. I'm looking for a string replacement bash command which can loop and create these password.

Tried `yq` but it has a bug where it removes some comments in the file.

Tried `sed` but not sure how to replace the `password-placeholder` with a unique password everytime.

Looking for suggestions.

Comment: Which yq version are you using? Go or the Python version? See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info and post your version details

Comment: I'm using the bash one I guess. This is the open issue -> https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/442

Comment: That's the go one, you can see that when you look at the sources

Comment: you'd need to add the `g` option to sed to apply your substitution to every `"password-placeholder"` occurences in your file

Comment: @Aserre Not really, only if you expect to need to replace multiple occurrences _per line._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `awk` for that:

```sh
awk -v placeholder='password-placeholder' '
    $0 ~ placeholder {
        cmd = "openssl rand -base64 12"
        cmd | getline pass
        close(cmd)
        sub(placeholder,pass)
    } 1
' file.yml
```

###### explanations:

- `$0 ~ placeholder {...}` selects the lines that match the **regex** contained in `placeholder` and executes `...` for them.
- `"openssl rand -base64 12" | getline pass` loads the result of the openssl command into the `pass` variable
- `sub(placeholder,pass)` replaces (in the current line) the first match of the regex `placeholder` with the content of `pass`
- `1` prints each line

Comment: Using this command substitutes same password in both placeholders. I'm thinking of looping over each line and then replace individually.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to close the command, now it should work as intented

Comment: Thanks, the print is coming correctly with `1`, is there a way to write it back to file. Seems like the original file is unchanged.

Comment: GNU awk have the option `awk -i inplace ...` for applying the changes to the input file

Comment: I tested -i inplace in my local system and it worked. But in the development environment we have some other flavor of linux which has either `mawk` or `gawk` and it gives error `awk: not an option: -i`. Do you know a workaround for this?

Comment: Using a simple temporary file is the only thing that's portable (not just for awk but with all other standard commands) `if awk ... > file.yaml.new; then mv -f file.yaml.new file.yaml; fi`